# Limit no of rows in live search json data using $.each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to limit no of rows I am getting in live search JSON data through URL I tried counting no of table rows and return false but it doesn't work, is there any way of doing it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
      });
      $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#state').val('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks? 
          city = MUMBAI ', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              var count = 0;

              if ((value.city.search(expression) != -1 ||
                  value.branch.search(expression) != -1) && count < 10) {
                $('#result').append('<tr><th>' + value.bank_name + '</th>' +
                  '<th>' + value.address + '</th>' +
                  '<th>' + value.ifsc + '</th>' +
                  '<th>' + value.branch + '</th>' +
                  '<th>' + value.bank_id + '</th></tr>'
                  count++;
                }
                else {
                  return false;
                }
              });
          });
      });
```

Comment: `if (count < 10 && value.city.search(expression) != -1)` OR `if (count >= 10) return false`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: its not working, is there any other way of displaying like top 10 records fetched in live search. @mplungjan

Comment: What does “it’s not working” mean? Error messages? How did you implement?

Comment: It shows all the rows from starting not even the searched one, and no error message. $.each(data, function(key, value) {var count = 0;
 if ( count < 10 && value.bank_name.search(expression) != -1)   $('#result').append('<tr><th>' + value.bank_name + '</th>' +
     '<th>' + value.bank_id + '</th></tr>');
  count++; } }); @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Try this - at least move the count=0 outside the loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
  });
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('#result').html('');
    $('#state').val('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('https://vast-shore-74260.herokuapp.com/banks?city=MUMBAI', function(data) {
      var count = 0;
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (count >= 10) return false;
        if (value.bank_name.search(expression) != -1) {
          $('#result').append('<tr><th>' + value.bank_name + '</th>' + '<th>' + value.bank_id + '</th></tr>');
          count++;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: it showed 10 results initially but after every 2 seconds, it keeps adding 10 more rows in the table. @mplungjan

Comment: That is only if you type. There is no interval in my code. You really should debounce the code